# find all possible combo pair in the list whose sum=0 in python using a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

The way to print is that the smaller number should be the first to print and the next.
Except two all the test cases are passing.
The idea behind the code is that am storing the numbers and their frequency in a dictionary and then am traversing through the dict and checking for -(number) and if present am printing the number as in the frequency and  making their frequency as 0

```
  def pairSum0(l):
       if len(l)==0:
            return
       map = {} 
       for num in l: #to store the freq of each number
           if num in map: 
              map[num] += 1 
           else: 
              map[num] = 1
       for i in map:
           if -i in map and map[i]!=0 and map[-i]!=0:
                      if map[i]==map[-i]:#k is getting the number of time the number is present
                            k=map[i]
                      if map[i]<map[-i]:
                            k=map[-i]
                      else:
                            k=map[i]
                      for j in range(k):
            
                              if -i<i:
                                  print(-i,i)
                              else:
                                   print(i,-i)
                              map[i]=0
                              map[-i]=0
        


   n=int(input())
   l=list(int(i) for i in input().strip().split(' '))
   pairSum0(l)
```

Where is the code getting the wrong results. Can anyone help me debug it?
one failed test case:
6
0 0 0 0 -1 1
my output
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
-1 1
wanted output:
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
0 0
-1 1

Comment: You haven't asked a question. Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: You could provide a test case. It would be better if you provide a failing case.

Comment: You may need a special case for 0, since your assumption that -i and i are different may not apply. And if you're wanting distinct combinations, just compute it from the count. There are formulas.

Comment: also the number of duplicate combinations will be different for positive and negative numbers which appear multiple times. itertools combinations might help with both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def pairsum(l):
    d = {}
    for i in l:
        if i not in d: d[i] = 0
        d[i] += 1
    for i in l:
        if i in d and (-i) in d:
            pair = f"{min(i,-i)} {max(i,-i)}"
            a,b = d[i],d[-i]
            if i != -i:
                for k in range(a*b):
                    print(pair)
                del d[i]
                del d[-i]
            else:
                for k in range(int(a*(a-1)/2)):
                    print(pair)
                del d[0]
```

The problem is that you can combine every integer `= i` with every other `= -i` meaning there are `amount(i)*amount(-i)` pairs. Zero is a special case because you can combine every zero with every other but not the same zero with itself which yields `n(n-1)/2` possibilities.